# Can't seem to get multiple network interfaces running at same time

Tags: networking, 20.04

I've looked around for questions similar to mine, and there are some, but they haven't seemed to solve the problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04LTS.  I have two network interfaces. 1 is connected via Ethernet(cat5) to router. The other is a tethered phone using USB.

On their own, each works perfectly fine. I try enabling them together, and only the first connected/enabled interface works.

What I would prefer is to have the Ethernet/Cat5 connection be priority, but have the tethered USB device available so it can be used for things like rsync (via rsync bind) and other software that allows me select interfaces.

Here is /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
source-directory interfaces.d
```

Any advice on what I should try next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ubuntu desktop or server ?

Comment: I'm using the desktop.